# weirdly connected edges

Tags: modeling, sculpting, retopology

I have weird marks (transition)[image] when connecting vertices, could you please give an advice?

[image]

Comment: The usual first steps in a situation like this are 1 - Check for duplicate vertices - select the whole mesh in edit mode and press M (merge) and select "by distance", and 2 - make sure normal orientation is correct for all the faces - select the whole mesh then press Shift+N (recalculate normals outside).

Comment: The edges might be creased (in that case, uncrease the edges). The result may be accurate and the geometry is a bit sharper than you intended.